# Can we prettify the "pending edit in queue page"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just wanted to edit a post when out of the blue the following showed up:

> [image: Pending edit]

I am intentionally posting a picture with barely any visible content because that is exactly what I got to see. Such a sight is, in my opinion, not acceptable on a 
busy site like stackexchange, and something should be done about it.

#### Walkthrough (mind the sequence points):

- Go to a question while it has no pending edit;
- Wait until someone else submits a pending edit;
- Click on the edit button;
- You should see a nearly blank site with only the text "There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes."

After reloading the question (while an edit is pending), the `Edit` button is greyed out and can't be clicked. That's why I think this "Error" happens very rarely. But never the less, it's an unpleasent view.

#### What I suggest:

When someone clicks the `Edit` Button while an edit is pending already, it show a red pop-up with the text instead:

> [image: Pending change]