# Ugly, text-only page containing an error when trying to edit a post that has a pending edit

Tags: feature-request, design, suggested-edits

I tried to edit a post, but it has a pending edit. So rather than show me a pop-up box, it leads me to a site:
[image]

I suspect this is a bug during the maintenance.

Do anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we prettify the "pending edit in queue page"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298848/can-we-prettify-the-pending-edit-in-queue-page) - While the route to get to the page has changed, the page itself still looks the same. Note that during maintenance, all bets are off though, the site is expected to not have all the usual bells and whistles